# Angular. How to hide data in the title attribute of the image if the object value is null?

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-show

I understand ng-show/ng-hide can be used but this case is a little different. This is my script below. Basically what I'm trying to do is hide the word "PEAK" if 'info.peak' value is empty in the title tag. DO I need to create two versions of this image tag? One with and without 'peak'? If show How would I do that also?

```
<img 
class="icon lazyloaded"  
data-ng-src="{{ info.image }}" 
alt="{{ info.title }}"  
title="Last Week: {{ info.lastweek}}  Move: {{ info.move }} Peak: {{ info.peak }}" 
width="100" 
height="100">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the following:

```
{{ info.peak ? 'Peak: ' + info.peak : '' }}
```

in place of where you have `Peak: {{ info.peak }}`.  So if `info.peak` does not exist/is null, it will simply append an empty string to the end.

Comment: You got it! Thanks very much